# Is there an application/tool to convert graphML to Dia or vice versa?

Tags: document-converter, xml

I have a situation where I have documents from two diagramming tools (yEd and Dia) and would like to convert between the two. Considering that both tools output XML files (.[graphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) for yEd and .dia for [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/doc/en/)), I would like to know if anybody's created a tool (even a number of plain [XSLT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764536516) files) to convert between the two (preferably not involving any intermediary files such as GraphViz dot files). Does such a thing exist or would I have to read up on GraphML, Dia XML, PERL and autodia?

**EDIT**:

I'll mainly be using this application while I'm at work, which entails using OS X. If you're going to suggest applications for a particular OS, that's first choice. However, the following criteria are not ruled out:

1. The OS that this application runs on is not important (preferably system agnostic or a *NIX/*BSD system, as it deals with XML).
2. A command-line application is preferable, as it's performing a transformation and doesn't need the overhead of a GUI (although a GUI application is acceptable).
3. A web-based application is also acceptable.
4. Using an XML DOM parser such as SAX is acceptable; exactly *how* the conversion is done is not important.

Comment: Do you care what OS it runs on? Also is a web-app okay? hmm and do you require a GUI or is a simple CLI option acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting those clarifications, @NickWilde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible.

From:  [Can I import a diagram from 'Dia' (http://yed.yworks.com/)](http://yed.yworks.com/support/qa/116/can-i-import-a-diagram-from-dia?show=118#a118)

> No, unfortunately not.
>
> Since Dia's native format is XML, you might be able to create an XSLT
>   stylesheet to transform (uncompressed) *.dia files to *.grapml. Due to
>   the different approaches to diagramming in Dia and yEd, this will
>   probably only work for rather simple diagrams (if it works at all)
>   where it is easy to map Dia shapes to yEd nodes and edges. answered
>   Oct 19, 2011 by thomas.behr [yWorks] (78,160 points)